# upgrade vue 2.7. vue-demi is missing in my vue project

Tags: vuejs2

I am updating my vue project to 2.7 (not vue3) and following this official instruction: https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto

It said I need to update vue-demi to ^0.13.1 however, I can't find vue-demi in anywhere in my vue project. Where can I find this?